# How to store password used for web scraping?

Tags: security, passwords, web-scraping, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm creating a web app (MyApp) which depends on information from another web app (AnotherApp). Every user in MyApp will have a profile synced with his AnotherApp profile. Obviously I'll scrape the data from AnotherApp, but I don't know how to correctly (in means of security) store and use users' credentials from AnotherApp. I need the credentials to authorise before syncing the data with AnotherApp.

So how to do it without making my users' passwords vulnerable?

Update:

Here's the context: it's about a legacy student system used in my university which kinda sucks and I want to provide a better experience to the students. I want to provide better data visualisation and data organisation. Also to add social element. There is no API and stuff, because legacy. I'll provide more details if needed.

Comment: Why are you duplicating data?  Why do you have to use web scraping to do it?  Why do you have to authenticate as each user to scrape the data?  It's not really clear what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: I'm not getting into details, because it's not so related to the problem. I want to accomplish the following: store password securely and use it for authentication to sync data. It was clear enough to me. Here's the context though: it's about a legacy student system used in my university which kinda sucks and I want to provide a better experience to the students. I want to provide better data visualisation and data organisation. Also to add social element. There so API and stuff, because legacy. I'll provide more details if needed.

Comment: Getting access to the legacy data source is probably going to be a lot easier and more effective.  With this approach there doesn't appear to be an option other than to have the actual text of your users' passwords, which isn't a good idea for your users.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the text representation approach, too. But getting access to the data is not an option. If it is even possible there will be too much bureaucracy to get access to the data and I don't have the time and desire to do it.

Comment: You were hired to perform this. So you have access to resources to accomplish it right? Like putting your app2 on their servers right next to theirs right?

Comment: No, I'm not hired to do it. I'm doing it as a side project of mine. Anyway, it seems that there is no way to accomplish this and preserve passwords' security.

Comment: If you describe more detail about the student interaction with the hybrid system perhaps you would get some answers. Spec it out for us. Right now it is just a large floating nebula no one technical can sink their head into

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing credentials of users for somebody else's system.  This is the whole point of [Oauth](http://oauth.net/2/).  Sure, you may think that you are a perfectly fine and honest person, but how are you going to respond about having student information on your app when it gets hacked?  Such a scenario is [not fiction](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2470329,00.asp).  So I highly advise you to consult your university for permission to work on this before you go ahead with it, and then discuss with them how you want to get authorisation to sync your app with theirs.  Any answer provided here that does not take into consideration the requirements of your university should not be followed.

Yes, I know, I didn't provide the answer you wanted, but for very good reason.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of what you say. I decided to have something like a sync button where a student enters his credential every time he wants to sync his account with his student information (exams, grades, etc). I'm not storing credentials.

Comment: _"Yes, I know, I didn't provide the answer you wanted, but for very good reason."_
    
Wat?

Comment: Not storing credentials is good, but a few points to mention from an attacker perspective: (1) If you are storing user data and your system gets hacked (like Snapsave), then you become responsible for the loss of other peoples' private data, and (2) if an attacker is able to get a [reverse shell](http://www.sans.edu/student-files/presentations/LVReverseShell.pdf) on your system then he can get access to any credentials that pass through your site, even if you are not storing them.  I am sceptical that a single person can provide 24-hour operational security of a system.